# databaseURL not found in Firestore SDK snippet

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a cloud firestore with Google Analytics enabled and I didn't find the `databaseURL` attribute in Firestore SDK snippet

Here's the CDN:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAx5I8j6ZkqCxQ3k1UgGkL5BuwhVK5xezA",
    authDomain: "ninja-firestore-tut-c5340.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "ninja-firestore-tut-c5340",
    storageBucket: "ninja-firestore-tut-c5340.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "326083693415",
    appId: "1:326083693415:web:5a8e21d6a0d90fec9d7dc2",
    measurementId: "G-2D61GV0P3Q"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `databaseURL` property is for the Firebase Realtime Database, which you probably didn't create yet. The `databaseURL` property is not necessary to use Firestore though, so you should be able to access that with just the configuration data you have. In fact, for Firestore all you should need is the `projectId` property.

Comment: but in a tutorial, the ```databaseURL``` attribute was in the Cloud firestore but in my case, there wasn't.

**Note**: The tutorial is from two years ago and yeah I didn't create ```Realtime Database```

Comment: Thanks Frank, I had an old node script for importing data, I removed the databae URL and used the service key as is and it worked fine. 

Answer (score 6):

Your databaseURL should look like this:

`https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com`

Here's where you can find the name of your project's firestore database:

[image]

Comment: While the `https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com` may be true for your Realtime Database, the pattern actually depends on what region you create your Realtime Database instance in. You can find the proper full URL for you Realtime Database from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database. But for Firestore just specifying the project ID is enough.

Comment: ok. that info might not be useful anymore with the latest versions of firebase, but for older ones, or people following tutorials, it might still be useful. My answer just aims to help those people and respond to the question  objectively, which I think it does

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case. I was using Retool and it asked for a database url, though I have only created a Firestore db. @FelipeChernicharo's answer worked.